# TypeScript Plugin on next.js isn't install on my VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js

I tried twice to start a basic project on Next.js, using TypeScript and with the version 13.4 of Next. But both of the time I never had the pop up in the bottom-right corner and the command ctrl+shift+p doesn't match with any "TypeScript" result.

I tried to install last version of the eslint-config-next without success. I'm not sure where the problem is

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue and I solved it by updating the node version

Comment: what version of Next.js are you on? see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77385372/11107541