# VS Code task to run Next.js v14 dev server throws "ReferenceError: Request is not defined", but the same command works in Terminal

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, next.js

I'm experiencing a weird bug whereby running `npm run dev` works in Terminal (shell), but it fails when executed as a VS Code *task*.

Here's what the error looks like

```
Executing task: npm run dev 


> deleteme@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

/Users/bgorman/Projects/deleteme/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request.js:28
class NextRequest extends Request {
                          ^

ReferenceError: Request is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bgorman/Projects/deleteme/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request.js:28:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at Module.mod.require (/Users/bgorman/Projects/deleteme/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:64:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bgorman/Projects/deleteme/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/adapters/next-request.js:37:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)

 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

This happens after I

1. Create a new Next.js project with `npx create-next-app@latest`
2. Create a `launch.json` file

   ```
   {
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
       {
         "type": "node",
         "request": "launch",
         "name": "Launch Program",
         "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
         "program": "${file}"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
3. Create a `tasks.json` file

   ```
   {
     "version": "2.0.0",
     "tasks": [
       {
         "type": "npm",
         "script": "dev",
         "label": "npm: dev",
         "detail": "next dev"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

Other people have reported this error and suggested upgrading node to v18,

- [Issue 1](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/57540)
- [Issue 2](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/57214)

but I'm already using node version v18.18.0. And like I said, `npm run dev` works fine - the error only occurs when I execute the VS Code task. (Someone else reported the [same behavior here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/57214#issuecomment-1783729932).)

##### Versions

- node 18.18.0
- npm  10.2.1
- nvm  0.39.5
- next 14.0.0
- vs code 1.83.1
- mac os 14.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had an old version of node installed that VS Code was using as the runtime for my tasks. Deleting the old runtime fixed it for me. [Helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69702082/2146894)

Answer (score 0):

***I faced same issue, Just Install Node latest version <=18.6.0***

Answer (score 0):

same issue - for me - I'd updated to the very latest version of node (21.1.0) but the node homepage was recommending the 20.9.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a bit of a further explanation for what's going on here, [Next.js v14](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v14.0.0) dropped support for NodeJS v16. Quoting from https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/version-14#v14-summary,

> The minimum Node.js version has been bumped from 16.14 to 18.17, since 16.x has reached end-of-life.

You can find the PR which implemented dropping support for NodeJS v16 at [feat: drop Node.js 16 #56896](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/56896).

If you need to, upgrade your NodeJS installation wherever you're deploying / testing your application in whatever way is appropriate ([download link](https://nodejs.org/en/download), system package manager, [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), etc.). If you don't give a full path to the Node binary when running, check also that you don't have any other unsupported NodeJS runtimes in the `PATH`. Ex. `whereis node` (UNIX) / `where node` (Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your task like this,

```
   {
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "label": "npm: dev",
      "detail": "next dev"
    }
```